# Honorary gifts?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the phrase *honorary gifts* to describe gifts that are given to honor someone? The normal usage of *honorary* is “given as an honor without the normal duties” (as in an *honorary* degree), which conveys quite a different implication.

Comment: No, it is not. *Gifts for Honor*, maybe. There could be a better term even.

Comment: @kris - "honorary gifts" turns up 47k Google results, while "gifts for honor" doesn't seem to be used except in phrases such as "gifts for honor students." Your comment is actually the second result in that search!

Comment: The first page consists of the term exclusively in "commercial usage", though. Try COCA instead.

Comment: Apparently, some spell it [honourary](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22honourary%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1994,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en), although this is an extremely rare use.

Comment: honouring/honoring gifts

Comment: @kurkevan, perhaps you can choose the reason for honoring the person as the "title" of the gift.  For example: if it is for a volunteer, you can call it a "Thank You" gift or a gift to recognize outstanding service in the community.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - the context is such as in the following sentence: "When the president visited our school, we presented him with a gold-plated American flag pin as an honorary gift."

Comment: @kurkevan In that context, would 'memento' work better?

Answer (score 2):

The word [honoraria](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honoraria?s=t) is used to convey gifts or payments made in this sense:

> a payment in recognition of acts or professional services for which
>   custom or propriety forbids a price to be set

However, if you actually mean that you are giving a gift *in their honor*, then "honorary gift" is a perfectly acceptable term. See, for example, the Metropolitan Opera's page on [Memory & Honorary Gifts](http://www.metoperafamily.org/metopera/support/gifts/index.aspx), or the results from [this search term](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=&q=intext%3ahonorary%20intext%3agift).

Answer (score 1):

[dictionary.reference.com's entry for honorary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honorary) includes the following definition:

> 5. given, made, or serving as a token of honor: **an honorary gift**.

While I have not come across the term (or received one, for that matter) myself, [Google's search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22honorary%20gifts%22) suggest that it is in use. Google Books also [provides some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22honorary%20gift%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks) of its usage.

According to the [University of Colorado Foundation](http://www.cufund.org/guide-to-giving/ways-to-give/honorary-gifts/):

> Honorary gifts are a meaningful way to pay tribute to a living person. It may honor a special occasion or achievement, or merely acknowledge the honoree’s importance in your life.
>
> Any type of gift can be designated as an honorary gift.

The [School of Public Health at UCB](http://sph.berkeley.edu/giving/gift.php) states:

> Honorary gifts commemorate a significant event or someone who is still living.

Therefore, it appears to be perfectly acceptable to honour someone with an honorary gift.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP would be unwise to use the expression *"honorary gifts"* for his intended sense. It's not a well-established term with a clear-cut meaning, but here's [one site's](http://greatergood.berkeley.edu/donate/memorial_gifts) take...

> A memorial gift can help perpetuate the values and ideals that defined a loved one’s life. **Honorary gifts** commemorate a significant event or an exceptional person who is still living.

I see many sites making a similar distinction between *memorial* and *honorary gifts*. My guess is they don't normally mean the *honorary* gift actually goes to the person being honoured. More likely you're making a gift/bequest to a "trust fund". Perhaps a trust set up by the person being honoured,  who is still alive; perhaps in honour of a sick relative who's about to die but hasn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "honorific gifts".
[Honorific](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/honorific#Adjective):

> Showing or conferring honour and respect.

That may not be ideal either, I tend to think of "honorific" as a *title*, e.g. **Lord Lieutenant** kurkevan.

Answer (score 0):

*Honorary gifts* is an uncommon and potentially confusing usage.   More typically you will find them dubbed **Honor Gifts**, **Gifts in Honor Of**, or **In Honor Gifts**.

See, for example:

- [American Kidney Foundation](http://www.kidneyfund.org/give-now/gifts-in-honor-of/) ("Gifts In Honor Of" / "Honor Gifts")
- [American Lung Association](http://www.lung.org/donate/memorial-honor-gifts/) ("Honor Gift")
- [American Health Assistance Foundation](http://www.ahaf.org/help/honormemory/honormemorygifts.html) ("In Honor Gift")

Answer (score 0):

While "token of appreciation" is often used for a small gesture that is meant to honor the person receiving the gift, "gift of appreciation" can also be used (11,500 hits on Google Books vs. 76,000 hits for "token of appreciation").