# What is a term for art, or other works, made of or about a particular person?

Tags: single-word-requests

In creating an outline for characters, I want to include a section for notable works (statues, songs, paintings, literature, etc.) made of or about that person. I'm not sure what to title this section.

A search of this site came up with [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/88094/288386) relating to honourary gifts, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I did consider the term *honoraria* from one of the answers though this doesn't seem to quite fit, either, as it refers to payment made. The term *honorific* is used for titles, and doesn't apply either.

It also doesn't necessarily need to include only works *in honour of,* as works of parody/satire or critique/derision would also be included.

Ideally, it should look something like this:

> --{{***TERM***}}--
>
> - *Some Painting*: A painting of John Doe...
> - *Some Statue:* A statue of John Doe found at...
> - *Some Ballad:* A ballad telling the tale of John Doe...

Bonus points if the term could also include works such as biographies and is not strictly limited to art.

---

Some possible example sentences:

- This collection of works, relating to a specific person is referred to as (a) ___.
- An individual referenced in many pieces of art and literary work has many ___.
- A heading for a section on historical works of art and literature about one individual would be called ___.

Comment: To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: @Greybeard Well, I did include how I want to use it, but I'll edit in some possible sentences. I don't want it limited that way, though, as a good answer may suggest a word that does not fit the sentence.

Comment: *I don't want it limited that way, though,* Although I see your point, the problem is that people will insert their own context, and you will not receive an accurate answer. Also, the result will be guesses and "opinion."

Comment: People think of a *bibliography* as only including books and articles, but it can include all kinds of media, and guides such as the MLA will tell you how to cite almost anything. You could list all works featuring a person in a bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

**Tributes to John Doe**:

> A painting by ...
>
> A statue by ...
>
> A ballad by ...

**tribute** (n.)

> An act, statement, or gift that is intended to show gratitude,
> respect, or admiration. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tribute?locale=en)

> A tribute is something that you say, do, or make to show your
> admiration and respect for someone. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tribute)

*Tribute* isn't appropriate for works of derision. It can include satirical and humorous works, including some books that are critical but balanced. However, I wouodn't say that all biographies are tributes. Perhaps "Tributes, Honors, and Works About or Inspired by ..." if there isn't a suitable single-word answer.

---

> Like the BCA's later monument..., the FCA's statue was a **tribute**
> to Dowding and all wartime Fighter Command Pilots. [Tony Joel; *The
> Dresden Firebombing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Dresden_Firebombing/haSmDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22statue%20was%20a%20tribute%20to%22&pg=PT213&printsec=frontcover)

> Bourne's friend, Simon Barr, used the controversy to fire off a
> **satirical tribute** to President Butler in the *Columbia Spectator*... [Bruce Clayton; *Forgotten Prophet: The Life of Randolph
> Bourne*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Forgotten_Prophet/nqhs1lDpQPgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22satirical%20tribute%20to%22&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover)

> When the book was published, Schoenberg wrote a furious letter to the
> Press, accusing Mann of intellectual theft. Mann, in a reasoned
> reply, said the **book** was a **tribute** to Schoenberg's tremendous
> influence on music. For two years relations between the composer and
> author remained embittered. [Normal Lebrecht; *Book of Musical
> Anecdotes*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Book_of_Musical_Anecdotes/YlT5qecRIMsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22book%20was%20a%20tribute%20to%22&pg=PA294&printsec=frontcover)

> The **statue** is a **tribute** to Sir Arthur Sullivan (1842–1900),
> who died from a heart attack at age 58. [Clara Gerhardt; *Families in
> Motion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Families_in_Motion/m3uuDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20%22statue%20is%20a%20tribute%22&pg=PT193&printsec=frontcover)

> His [Asher Brown Durand's] most famous **painting** was a **tribute** to Cole and to Bryant: two
> figures standing on a high rock above a waterfall in mountainous
> landscape, little figures in a big place, called "Kindred Spirits."
> [Russell Lynes; *The Art-Makers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_makers/NyTZ3WQVrDEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22painting%20was%20a%20tribute%20to%22&pg=PA212&printsec=frontcover)

> Inspired by a party honoring the 37th wedding anniversary of Richie's
> parents, the **ballad** was a **tribute** to the three most important
> women in Richie's life... [David Ewen; *American Songwriters*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Songwriters/TZsYAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the%20ballad%20was%20a%20tribute%20to%22&dq=%22the%20ballad%20was%20a%20tribute%20to%22&printsec=frontcover)

> This anonymous **ballad** is a **tribute** to Nathan Hale, hanged as a spy
> Sept. 22, 1776. [A. G. Newcomer et al.; *Three Centuries of American
> Poetry and Prose*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Three_Centuries_of_American_Poetry_and_P/JwcuAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20%22ballad%20is%20a%20tribute%22%20to%20poem&pg=PA151&printsec=frontcover)

> A **comical tribute** to newswoman Barbara Walters by the Friars Club.
> [Vincent Terrace; *Television Specials*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comical%20tribute%20to%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvK4oUZBeGMj7XGW2XBVB4qCAzSS1Q%3A1634410518687&ei=FiBrYZzGKdKwytMP1_mO8As&oq=%22comical%20tribute%20to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...50835.51752.0.51943.8.8.0.0.0.0.102.721.5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.101...0i13k1.0.FEu9k34pQgo)

> Mr. Chief Justice:
> It is a supreme satisfaction officially to accept
> on behalf of the Government this superb **monument** to the savior of the
> republic...This memorial edifice is a noble **tribute**, gratefully
> bestowed... [President Harding's Address at the Dedication of the
> Lincoln Memorial](https://www.google.com/books/edition/President_Harding_s_Address_at_the_Dedic/OsJAzCn6bFAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20receive%20tribute,%20paintings,%20dedications&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: And I guess the antonym could be along the lines of *dishonours* or *criticisms.* The section could just be "Tributes & Criticisms" or something similar. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it:

Legacy

Cultural Depictions

In Culture

or something similar, and break it down ny media type, e.g., film, biography, statuary, fictional accounts, etc. Whatever is relevant.

Comment: I like "In Culture." Oddly, I used Legacy for the larger section this is a part of.

Answer (score 0):

The collected body of a person's works is their oeuvre.  But that only refers to works by the person, not by others about the person.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Comment: Hey there! The Stack doesn't work like a traditional forum. I do recommend the links livresque gave you to get acquainted. Happy Stacking!